# Investigating the differentiability of $f(x) = |\pi x|sinx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have the function

$$f(x) = |\pi  - x|\sin x$$

Since $\sin x$ is bounded between -1 and 1 the function $A\sin x$ only changes its amplitude $\forall  x \in \mathbb{R}$, where $A(x) = |\pi-x|$, then we can consider the following equivalent function:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}(\pi- x) \sin x &\mbox{if, }0\leq x\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\\
-(\pi-x)\sin x &\mbox{if, }-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq x<0
\end{cases}$$

The only place where the function could not be differentiable here is when $x = 0$. Suppose that it is differentiable at this point. Then the one-sided derivatives exist and are equal to each other. That is

$$\lim_{h\to 0^{-}} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to 0^{-}} \frac{f(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}} \frac{f(h)}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to 0^{-}} -\frac{(\pi- h)\sin h}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}} \frac{(\pi- h)\sin h}{h}$$

$$\lim_{h\to 0^{-}} -\frac{\pi\sin h}{h}+\lim_{h\to 0^{-}}\sin h=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}} \frac{\pi\sin h}{h}-\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\sin h$$

$$-\pi+ \lim_{h\to 0^{-}}\sin h= \pi+\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\sin h$$

$$-\pi = \pi$$

So the function is not differentiable at $x = 0$. But according to my textbook, the function is differentiable everywhere.

I'm stuck. I'd would appreciate is somebody can point out what I'm doing wrong (and the way to prove its everywhere differentiability).

Comment: it is $\pi x$, not $\pi-x$, $|\pi x|=\pi x$, if $x \ge 0$, and $|\pi x|=-\pi x$, if $x\lt 0$

Answer (score 2):

You have written the wrong equivalent function. What you should have written is
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
-\pi x\sin x&x<0\\
\pi x\sin x&x\ge0
\end{cases}$$
Clearly $f(x)$ is differentiable whenever $x\ne0$. To prove differentiability at $x=0$, we can take the one-sided limits as you did:
$$\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}h=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(h)}h=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{-\pi h\sin h}h=\lim_{h\to0^-}-\pi\sin h=0$$
$$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}h=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(h)}h=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{\pi h\sin h}h=\lim_{h\to0^+}\pi\sin h=0$$
Since both limits agree, $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\pi |x| \frac{sinx}{x} \to \pi*0*1=0$  as $x \to 0$

FRED

Comment: How did you get the second equation?